# I need to count how many days per year were at least 85 degrees

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

These are the libraries I have loaded and use for class. I have pasted my code below. I get a table of each day that was 85 degrees or more but I can't figure out how to get the count of how many days there were each year. I have to plot it too. Help please! Thank you in advance

```
filter(phl_weather,AvgTemperature>85)%>%
 group_by(AvgTemperature,day,year)%>%
ggplot(aes(x = year,y = AvgTemperature)) +
geom_point(colour = "blue") +
geom_smooth(colour = "red",size = 1, se = FALSE)
```

Comment: `phl_weather %>% group_by(AvgTemperature > 85) %>% tally()` will return a count. As for a chart, there are many ways to plot that information, and it's not up to the community to determine how to plot it.

Answer (score 0):

After you filter on `AvgTemperature`, you can `select()` the columns `day` and `year`, then call `unique()`. This avoids duplicate rows for the same day. Then you can go ahead and `count(year)`.

```
phl_weather %>%
    filter(AvgTemp >= 85) %>%
    select(day, year) %>%
    unique() %>%
    count(year)
```

(If you want days that are "85 degrees or more" then you should use `>=` rather than `>`.)